# Optimal solution for this interview question

Tags: optimization

Can anyone provide optimal solution with Time Complexity? Very appreciated!

Determine bandwidth required to run prescheduled video streams.
There can be 10s of thousands of streams and all the scheduling data is available at the start.
There may be time intervals when no streams are running

Inputs

```
int startTime; //start time for the stream  
int duration; //how long the stream runs  
int bandwidth; // consumed bandwidth from start to end
```

Output:

```
list[int] totalBW; // bandwidth needed at every time instant
```

**Example**:
input (list may not sorted)

```
[ [0,2,10], [1,2,10], [2,1,20] ]
```

output

```
[10, 20, 30]
```

**Explanation**

```
At time 0: only the first element needs bandwidth 10 =>  [10, ...]
At time 1: first two elements need bandwidth 10 + 10 => [10, 20, ...]
At time 2: the second and third element need bandwidth 10 + 20 => [10, 20, 30]
```

The brute force approach using python:

```
def solution(streams):
    _max = max(streams, key=lambda x: (x[0]+x[1]))
    _max_time = _max[0] + _max[1] 
    res = [0] * _max_time
        
    for s, d, bw in streams:
        for i in range(d):
            res[s+i] += bw
    return res
```

Is there any more efficient approach?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any more efficient approach?

Yes.

The first step would be to transform the original data into a set of "at time = T, bandwidth changes by N" events, sorted in chronological order, and simplified by merging events that happen at the same time.

For your example, if the input is `[ [0,2,10], [1,2,10], [2,1,20] ]`  then it would be broken up into:

```
** [ [0,2,10] **
    At 0, bandwidth += 10 
    At 2, bandwidth += -10

** [1,2,10] **
    At 1, bandwidth += 10
    At 3, bandwidth += -10

** [2,1,20] **
    At 2, bandwidth += 20
    At 3, bandwidth += -20
```

..then sorted and simplified (merging events that happen at the same time - e.g. `bandwidth += -10, bandwidth += 20` becomes a single `bandwidth += 10`) to get:

```
At 0, bandwidth += 10 
At 1, bandwidth += 10
At 2, bandwidth += 10
At 3, bandwidth += -30
```

From there it's a simple matter of generating the final array from the sorted list:

```
 10, 20, 30, 0
```

To understand why this is more efficient, imagine what happens if the time is tracked with higher precision (e.g. maybe milliseconds instead of seconds) and the input is `[ [0,2000,10], [1000,2000,10], [2000,1000,20] ]`  instead. For my approach generating the final array would become an outer loop with 4 iterations and an inner loop that can be a highly optimized `memset()` (C) or `rep stosd` (80x86 assembly) or `np.full()` (Python with NumPy); and for your approach the outer loop needs 30000 iterations where the inner loop wastes a huge amount of time repeating a linear search that (for most iterations of the outer loop) finds the same answer as the previous iteration of the outer loop.